# Shell script to remove new line after numeric string

Tags: bash, shell, sed, newline

I need to write a SHELL Script to remove new line after only after a numeric string? or after string doesn't start with number. For example a have a file:

```
asasas
12345
adab-123
123
```

I need output like this:

```
asasas 12345
adab-123 123
```

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` Just split it to:

```
asasas12345
adab-123123
```

And `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'` give me a:

```
asasas 12345 adab-123 123
```

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I've edited it to make it more readable but I'm not sure if my edit is correct. If it is not correct please re-edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go!

```
[jaypal~]$ cat file9
asasas
12345
adab-123
123

[jaypal~]$ sed '{N;s/\n/ /g}' file9
asasas 12345
adab-123 123
[jaypal~]$
```

Comment: Yes. It works. Thank you.
Can you pls. explain how it work? 
Each next(N) line after first one substitute to new line (/n)?

Comment: Well the script reads the next line in to buffer (using N) and substitutes the new line with a space. This does not do any checks on the line. Every second line will be appended to the line before it.

Comment: Ok. I see. Is it possible to tell to sed check number string and put new line only! after it?

Comment: Ofcourse. But in your desired output it looks like you are removing the new line instead of adding it. Can you please update the question so that it is more clearer?

Comment: :) You should have updated this question instead of opening another question. Also, please accept the answers if they happen to resolve your question or provide enough information to get you in the right direction.