# write a SHELL Script to substitute new line to tab

Tags: bash, shell, sed, newline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shell script to remove new line after numeric string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284730/shell-script-to-remove-new-line-after-numeric-string)

I need to write a SHELL Script to remove new line \n after string doesn't start with number and substitute it to tab \t or for 5 spaces for example.
For example a have a file:

```
asasas
12345
adab-123
123
```

I need output like this:

```
asasasi   12345
adab-123    123
```

Comment: ... and what have you tried so far? Which part is giving you trouble? SO is for programming questions, not for writing your code for you. Though I'll provide a pointer: look at the `sed` command (but I guess you know that), or `perl` or `awk`. You could do it without them using the shell-builtin `read` as well.

Comment: Yea I think so. His question was a little ambiguous and I had asked him to update his question. I didn't find a marker to close the other question.

Answer (score 1):

This should work -

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ cat file9
asasas
12345
adab-123
123
fffd
223
2323
afdf
23234
```

**with tab:**

```
[jaypal~/Temp]$ sed '/^[0-9]/!{N;s/\n/\t/}' file9
asasas  12345
adab-123    123
fffd    223
2323
afdf    23234
```

Comment: Thank you Jaypal.
Exclamation here is a NOT DIGIT statement?

Comment: I didn't quite follow you. If you are asking about the `!` next to the RegEx then it means `NOT`. So basically we are telling sed to run for only those lines which `Do not start with a number`. `^` states start of the line.

Comment: Yes. What was a missing statement for me. Thank you a lot again.

Comment: No problem. If you are satisfied with the answer and the explanation, don't forget to accept the answer. Just click on the `checkmark` so that it is green. :)

Comment: @Jaypal a small quibble... perhaps `N` should be changed to `$!N`

Answer (score 0):

The awk way =)

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{print} !/^[0-9]/{printf("%s\t", $0)}' file
```

same output as Jaypal.

Comment: Minimalistic way!! ;) `awk '!/^[0-9]/{printf("%s\t", $0);next}1' file`

Comment: The brevity - sister of talent !